# Is there any way to identify the plugin names that were activated on my website before migration of the website to another domain?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, migration

I can't restore my website to its original state because I did not recorded the activated plugin names before moving the site to another domain name.

I use Linux hosting plan, MySql and Wordpress.

Comment: When you say you migrated your site, did you copy the database?  Did you change web hosts or just change domain names? The [WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) has a full how-to for migrating WordPress Sites.   Also this probably isn't the right forum for this type of question - it'd be more appropriate at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Justin R., Yes, I copied the database and reupload it. I did not change web host, neither the domain name. Do you have any idea what direction I should take to solve this issue ? Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the database, checking the `active_plugins` key under the `wp_options` table may be where you should start.

Comment: @nara_lThank you for your reply. Where can I find the wp_options field under mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

Upload https://www.adminer.org/en/ Adminer (a one file database management tool written in PHP) to the root of the host and site - probably in `public_html` - and go to example.com/adminer.php (or use the IP 123.45.56.321/adminer.php if DNS hasn't been pointed to the host) and select the wp_options table. Search for the `active_plugins` key.

Comment: Thanks. Can't i use mysql php admin under my hosting package ?

Comment: Sure, if they have it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried what you suggested and the key "options framework" contains the following entry or value: "options-framework/options-framework.php". Can I find the earlier activated plugin names in that file ? I'd very appreciate your help because without plugin names I just can't restore my website to its original state.

Comment: IDK; look in that file options-framework/options-framework.php and see what's there.

Comment: @ BlueDogRanch, Unfortunately, it looks like it only contains some information about "options-framework" plugin but nothing on other plugins. Do you have any further idea which direction I should go to solve this matter ? It would be fine to find a way of looking into plugin activation history or something like that..